# How to understand to_timestamp for conversion from String to Timestamp in Spark Scala?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm confused by to_timestamp function since its two formats to_timestamp(s: Column, fmt: String) and to_timestamp(s: Column) have very different results

I've tried with the following scenarios:

```scala
val dfMilli = Seq(
("2019-02-19 03:14:12.254", "20190219T031412.254"),
("9999-12-31 23:23:41.182", "99991231T232341.182")
).toDF("Standard", "Formatted")

val dfMicro = Seq(
("2019-02-19 03:14:12.254183", "20190219T031412.254183"),
("9999-12-31 23:23:41.182109", "99991231T232341.182109")
).toDF("Standard", "Formatted")

val dfNano = Seq(
("2019-02-19 03:14:12.254183893", "20190219T031412.254183893"),
("9999-12-31 23:23:41.182109821", "99991231T232341.182109821")
).toDF("Standard", "Formatted")
```

Then I calculated conversions using to_timestamp on both columns "Standard" and "Formatted".

```scala
val dfMilliTs = dfMilli
  .withColumn("StandardTs", to_timestamp('Standard))
  .withColumn("FormattedTs", to_timestamp('Formatted, "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS"))

val dfMicroTs = dfMicro
  .withColumn("StandardTs", to_timestamp('Standard))
  .withColumn("FormattedTs", to_timestamp('Formatted, "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSSSS"))

val dfNanoTs = dfNano
  .withColumn("StandardTs", to_timestamp('Standard))
  .withColumn("FormattedTs", to_timestamp('Formatted, "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSSSSSSS"))
```

And get results:

```
scala> dfMilliTs.show(false)
+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|Standard               |Formatted          |StandardTs             |FormattedTs        |
+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|2019-02-19 03:14:12.254|20190219T031412.254|2019-02-19 03:14:12.254|2019-02-19 03:14:12|
|9999-12-31 23:23:41.182|99991231T232341.182|9999-12-31 23:23:41.182|9999-12-31 23:23:41|
+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+


scala> dfMicroTs.show(false)
+--------------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+-----------+
|Standard                  |Formatted             |StandardTs                |FormattedTs|
+--------------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+-----------+
|2019-02-19 03:14:12.254183|20190219T031412.254183|2019-02-19 03:14:12.254183|null       |
|9999-12-31 23:23:41.182109|99991231T232341.182109|9999-12-31 23:23:41.182109|null       |
+--------------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+-----------+


scala> dfNanoTs.show(false)
+-----------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+
|Standard                     |Formatted                |StandardTs                |FormattedTs|
+-----------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+
|2019-02-19 03:14:12.254183893|20190219T031412.254183893|2019-02-19 03:14:12.254183|null       |
|9999-12-31 23:23:41.182109821|99991231T232341.182109821|9999-12-31 23:23:41.182109|null       |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+
```

So you see, there are very different results among two styles of to_timestamp function:

1. to_timestamp(s: Column) can convert **milli and micro seconds** timestamp to TimestampType correctly.
2. For **nano seconds**, to_timestamp(s: Column) can handle it, but just cut down it to **micro sends**
3. to_timestamp(s: Column, fmt: String) can only support **milli seconds**, but it cuts down string to only **seconds** even.
4. Do you think I used wrong format strings?

I know TimestampType in Spark is based on java.sql.Timestamp, which is subclass of java.util.Date and only support miliseconds. But these two styles of to_timestamp convert string with very different logic? Could to_timestamp(s: Column, fmt: String) support conversation better?

**Update**:

Based on spark codes on Github: [datetimeExpressions.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1b7afc0c986ed8e5431df351f51434424460f4b3/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressiousns/datetimeExpressions.scala)

I got definitions of these two styles of to_timestamp functions.

1. Standard style to_timestamp(s: Column) has the implementation: Cast(left, TimestampType) --- directly using Cast function
2. Formatted style to_timestamp(s: Column, fmt: String) has the implementation GetTimestamp(left, format) --- another function GetTimestamp

Next, I need more investigation on both functions Cast and GetTimestamp.

**Update**:

Seem like the Spark version of the master snapshot has fixed this problem now. [[SPARK-27438]](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/79d3bc0409ccf978126d9c2bc0740ace196fe55b#diff-b83497f7bc11578a0b63a814a2a30f48)

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_181)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

It is very good, and here are new results -- to_timestamp(s: Column, fmt: String) can support **micro-seconds**, and no errors for **nano format string**. Great!:

```
scala> dfMilliTs.show(false)
+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|Standard               |Formatted          |StandardTs             |FormattedTs            |
+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|2019-02-19 03:14:12.254|20190219T031412.254|2019-02-19 03:14:12.254|2019-02-19 03:14:12.254|
|9999-12-31 23:23:41.182|99991231T232341.182|9999-12-31 23:23:41.182|9999-12-31 23:23:41.182|
+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+


scala> dfMicroTs.show(false)
+--------------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|Standard                  |Formatted             |StandardTs                |FormattedTs               |
+--------------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|2019-02-19 03:14:12.254183|20190219T031412.254183|2019-02-19 03:14:12.254183|2019-02-19 03:14:12.254183|
|9999-12-31 23:23:41.182109|99991231T232341.182109|9999-12-31 23:23:41.182109|9999-12-31 23:23:41.182109|
+--------------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+


scala> dfNanoTs.show(false)
+-----------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|Standard                     |Formatted                |StandardTs                |FormattedTs               |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|2019-02-19 03:14:12.254183893|20190219T031412.254183893|2019-02-19 03:14:12.254183|2019-02-19 03:14:12.254183|
|9999-12-31 23:23:41.182109821|99991231T232341.182109821|9999-12-31 23:23:41.182109|9999-12-31 23:23:41.182109|
+-----------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: You could argue it's correct since S denotes milliseconds in the specification. SSSSSS doesn't make sense in that context. That said timeconversions with fractions in Spark is something to look out for. The documentation doesn't say anything in particular about the default conversion method but apparently it's limited to micro seconds as you just found out.

Comment: Thank you, Molotch. I've learned your research on to_timestamp in the link: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54601917/spark-2-4-0-unable-to-parse-iso8601-string-into-timestamptype-preserving-ms). :-)